# After update backend error 500

Tags: magento-1.9, error, upgrade, backend

I upgraded Package for Magento CE 1.9.1 to 1.9.3 with Magento Connect Manager and have now Error 500 when trying to log into admin. Backup uploading did not seem to help. File permission with magento-cleanup.php.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
2017-08-13T22:41:39+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /html/{magento-directory}/app/code/local/TSM/Maian/Helper/Data.php on line 30
2017-08-13T22:41:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: rootCatId  in /html/{magento-directory}/app/code/local/TSM/Quicksearch/Model/System/Config/Source/ListCategory.php on line 50
2017-08-13T22:41:39+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /html/{magento-directory}/app/code/local/TSM/Maian/Helper/Data.php on line 30
2017-08-13T22:41:40+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getBaseDir() must be of the type array, none given, called in /html/{magento-directory}/app/design/frontend/tsm_maian/default/template/tsm/blocks/related2.phtml on line 64 and defined  in /html/{magento-directory}/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 318
2017-08-13T22:41:40+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::updateParamDefaults() must be of the type array, null given, called in /html/{magento-directory}/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 320 and defined  in /html/{magento-directory}/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 298
2017-08-13T22:41:40+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: _type  in /html/{magento-directory}/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 322
2017-08-13T22:41:40+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: class  in /html/{magento-directory}/app/design/frontend/tsm_maian/default/template/tsm/blocks/product-block.php on line 8
2017-08-13T22:41:40+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: uniqued  in /html/{magento-directory}/app/design/frontend/tsm_maian/default/template/tsm/blocks/product-block.php on line 94
```

Comment: Try to check with disabling third party extension

Comment: More specifically, disable module TSM_Maian

Answer (score 0):

First of all enable developer mode at index.php and check if error appears at the screen if no - check var/log/system.log and var/log/system.log, than try to restore .htaccess - It's often the reason of 500 error

Comment: Fatal error: ´Class 'IntegerNet_MagentoLocalizedEbay_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Head' not found in /html/{magento-directory}/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491´     

**In Layout.php:**
          ´ if (class_exists($block, false) || mageFindClassFile($block)) {
                $block = new $block($attributes);
            }´

Comment: It seems that it is problem with name of localized module

Comment: Just disable it temporarily setting false at at the tag <active> app/etc/modules/IntegerNet_MagentoLocalizedEbay.xml if your target is not fix this issue. If you need it - it looks like there is a lack of IntegerNet_MagentoLocalizedEbay_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Head class in MagentoLocalizedEbay module.

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask for help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an issue with your magento. If you get an internal server error then you should first check your server. in your case its error 500 so please check your PHP configurations. Also you should check the file permission. change the file permission for Magento files and try again.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/*
```

this might fix your problem.